# Android permissions in Angular 6 using Cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, android-permissions

I have an angular project that's made but now I need to make it for mobile apps using Cordova. Everything is working fine on Android < 6 (I have the permissions stated in the manifest), but I don't know how to ask for permissions in real time needed for Android > 6.

I found some Cordova and NativeScript plugins  but I don't know how to use them in my Angular TypeScript environment.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/